# How to ask input until ctrl+D in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with writing program to ask input for counting vowels. My problem is about asking input. in this version program ask an input and counts its vowels successfuly. However I want to find way to ask inputs until user push CTRL+D and then show result. I used `while(scanf("%[^\n]", a) !=EOF)` but it stucked in loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[150];
    int i;
    int vowels;
    vowels=0;
    scanf("%[^\n]", a);
    for(i=0; a[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i]=='a' || a[i]=='A' || a[i]=='e' || a[i]=='E' || a[i]=='i' || 
           a[i]=='I' || a[i]=='o' || a[i]=='O' || a[i]=='u' || a[i]=='U') {
            ++vowels;
        }
    }
    printf("Vowels: %d\n",vowels);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `fgets` and check its return value. It will be `NULL` on EOF.

Comment: wrapping scanf in a while loop should work, but it's hard to say since you haven't actually included that code.  Include the code that isn't working for you rather than the code that is.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `while(scanf("%[^\n]", a)) != EOF` will not work. On the first call `scanf` will consume all the characters up to the new line, NOT INCLUDING the new line into the input buffer `a`.

On the next call to `scanf`, the code will see the new line that was not consumed in the first call, and will immediately terminate the scanf with buffer of zero  length (""). This sequence will repeat for the 3rd, 4th, ... calls, giving the user the impression that the program is `stucked in a loop`, it really is.

Few options to solve the problem:

1. Switch to fgets/sscanf, as suggsted by Eugene Sh, OR
2. Modify the format to 'sscanf(" %[^\n], a)` which will allow the code to skip over white spaces (including the new line) before reading the next input.
3. Modify the format to `sscanf("%[^\n]%*1[\n]", a)`, which will read the token (without the new line), and then skip the new lines (if one exists) after the string.

Personally, I will go with #1. But for this problem, all of them will work. Probably #2 is least amount of work.